# как можно с помощью кнопки добавить перед последним абзацем изображение на языке Javascript?

Tags: javascript

как можно с помощью кнопки добавить перед последним абзацем изображение?
Что нужно добавлять в ?

Comment: На самом деле в зависимости от разметки варианты могут быть разными

Comment: "Что нужно добавлять в ?" - вопрос выглядит не закончено. Если вы хотели спросить -"Что нужно добавить в вопрос, чтобы он был понятен ?", то это ваш код.

Comment: Добавьте ваш [mcve], что у вас не получается, опишите подробнее какого результата хотите достичь, тогда вам помогут

Answer (score 1):

Если я что-то правильно понял, то:

Вариант 1

```js
function addImage() {
    // Создаем новый <img>
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    // добавляем картинку
    img.src = 'https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2015/12/15/11/20151215114126414/pic_a8bf01cef0eaf46338e791bf08db72c1.jpg';
    var paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("#wrap p");
    // Элемент, перед которым вставить картинку
    var lastParagraph = paragraphs[paragraphs.length-1];
    //Получаем ссылку на родителя testElement
    var parentDiv = lastParagraph.parentNode;

    // Вставляем img перед последним paragraph
    parentDiv.insertBefore(img, lastParagraph);
}

let btn = document.querySelector("button");
// Добавляет слушателя событий для таблицы
btn.addEventListener("click", addImage, false);
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
rewrwe
<p>sdfsdfsdf</p>

<div>123</div>

<p>Последний абзац</p>
</div>

<button>нажми мая кнопачка</button>
```

[insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) - добавляет элемент в  список дочерних элементов родителя перед указанным элементом.

```
var insertedElement = parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, referenceElement);
```

- `insertedElement` - Вставленный элемент.
- `parentElement` - Родитель для нового элемента.
- `newElement` - Элемент для вставки.
- `referenceElement` - Элемент, перед которым будет вставлен `newElement`.

---

Вариант 2

```js
function addImage() {
  let paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("#wrap p");
  // Элемент, перед которым вставить картинку
  let lastParagraph = paragraphs[paragraphs.length-1];

  lastParagraph.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', '<img src="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2015/12/15/11/20151215114126414/pic_a8bf01cef0eaf46338e791bf08db72c1.jpg"/>');

}

let btn = document.querySelector("button");
// Добавляет слушателя событий для таблицы
btn.addEventListener("click", addImage, false);
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
rewrwe
<p>sdfsdfsdf</p>

<div id="test">123</div>


<p>Последний абзац</p>
</div>

<button>кнопачка нажми</button>
```

[insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) -  вставляет полученные узлы (nodes) в DOM дерево в указанную позицию.

```
element.insertAdjacentHTML(position, text);
```

1. `beforeBegin` -- перед `elem`.
2. `afterBegin` -- внутрь `elem`, в самое начало.
3. `beforeEnd` -- внутрь `elem`, в конец.
4. `afterEnd` -- после `elem`.